# Bind DataGridView to Entities in a "master-detail" manner

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

I'm trying to establish a master-detail relation between two DataGridView.
I have an EntityModel with two entities connected by "ClientComissions" Association.
They were generated from an existing DB, and have Navigation Properties, that work well.
Proof (console app using mentioned EntityModel):

---

```
            using (var context = new MnxEntities())
        {
            Client client = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault();
            // profiler: "SELECT TOP (1) ... FROM [Clients] AS [c]" - Ok!
            Console.WriteLine("Client: {0}", client.Name);
                foreach (Comission comission in client.NavComissions)
                // profiler: "SELECT ... FROM [Comissions] WHERE [StateCode] = '20971504'" - Ok!
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Agreement number: {0}", comission.Dog_Num);
                }
        }
```

---

But I can't bind two DataGridViews in a master-detail manner on windows form:

---

```
        private void tabComissions_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new MnxEntities())
        {
            clientDataGridView.DataSource  = context.Clients;

            comissionsDataGridView.DataSource = clientDataGridView.DataSource;
            comissionsDataGridView.DataMember = "WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?";
        }
    }
```

---

I know there is a BindingContext, that must do all the job using CurrencyManager, with no hand-written code needed.

I've stuck here for to much time. Help please.

---

UPD:

```
        private void AnswerFromStackRefactored()
    {
        using (var context = new MnxEntities())
        {
            clientBindingSource.DataSource = context;
            clientBindingSource.DataMember = "Clients";

            navComissionsBindingSource.DataSource = clientBindingSource;
            navComissionsBindingSource.DataMember = "NavComissions";
        }

    }
```

this code loads Comissions only once, for the first client in grid.
But when I change Current row in Clients Grid there is no more query to DB and navComissionsGrid always show comission for the first client. :(

Answer (score 0):

Pull two ListViews on a Form and name them as lstcategory and lstProduct respectively. Then copy the code below [its very simple]. You may apply the same concept to your problem.

```
public partial class MasterDetail : Form
    {
        public MasterDetail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private BindingManagerBase categoryBinding;
        private DataSet ds;

        private void MasterDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ds = GetCategoriesAndProducts();

            // Bind the lists to different tables.
            lstCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables["Categories"];
            lstCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";

            lstProduct.DataSource = ds.Tables["Products"];
            lstProduct.DisplayMember = "ProductName";

            // Track the binding context and handle position changing.
            categoryBinding = this.BindingContext[ds.Tables["Categories"]];
            categoryBinding.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(Binding_PositionChanged);

            // Update child table at startup.
            UpdateProducts();
        }

        private void Binding_PositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateProducts();
        }

        private void UpdateProducts()
        {
            string filter;
            DataRow selectedRow;

            // Find the current category row.
            selectedRow = ds.Tables["Categories"].Rows[categoryBinding.Position];

            // Create a filter expression using its CategoryID.
            filter = "CategoryID='" + selectedRow["CategoryID"].ToString() + "'";

            // Modify the view onto the product table.
            ds.Tables["Products"].DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }

        public DataSet GetCategoriesAndProducts()
        {
            DataTable category = new DataTable("Categories");
            category.Columns.Add("CategoryID");
            category.Columns.Add("CategoryName");

            category.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Food" });
            category.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Beverage" });


            DataTable product = new DataTable("Products");
            product.Columns.Add("CategoryID");
            product.Columns.Add("ProductName");

            product.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Rice" });
            product.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Pasta" });

            product.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Cola" });
            product.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Coffee" });
            product.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Tea" });


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(category);
            ds.Tables.Add(product);

            // Set up a relation between these tables (optional).
            DataRelation relCategoryProduct = new DataRelation("CategoryProduct",
              ds.Tables["Categories"].Columns["CategoryID"],
              ds.Tables["Products"].Columns["CategoryID"]);

            ds.Relations.Add(relCategoryProduct);

            return ds;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: There is a difference between DataSet and EntityDataModel.

Comment: They're all good technologies for data access in .NET. Typed dataset is an old one and for now, ADO.NET Entity Framework(EF) is the new one. As to the reason, EF can handle the relationships in database better. Also, it can take adavantage of LINQ technology and is more convenient to use. But, that should not be a blocker for you ? I have highlighted the solution to the problem which you were asking in a working prototype. Now, you should be able to derive out your own solution from this concept.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but still, I tried to find a way to work with EF and WinForms. I know how to work with the DataSet. As for result of my investigation - there is no straight way to "codeless" master-detail binding to EF. There is an open source project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms that do the trick.

Comment: Dude! Why a downvote ... provide a solution instead !